# Sqlite SELECT query not working

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to do a query on my android database in my program that is not working.
I have this:

```
    String selectQuery = "SELECT content_title,content_body,cat_title FROM categories INNER JOIN content  ON content.cat_id = categories.cat_id WHERE categories.cat_title="+category;
```

What is that i have wrong on this query?

Comment: You question lacks sufficient information to obtain a useful response. You need to show what the error message is, indicate what you have tried and provide details of OS and language versions. Your SQL is also incorrect as it references tables not in your from clause - suggest reading up on SQL

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but my problem was awnsered by the user below. The problem was only on the SQL, so i didn't feel the need to put more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
categories.cat_id = categories.cat_id
```

you probably meant

```
categories.cat_id = content.cat_id 
                    ^^^^^^^
```

also you can change this:

```
="+category;
```

to:

```
='"+category+"'";
 ^            ^
```

Comment: categories.cat_id = categories.cat_id, i had this right but i misstyped here lol. The second part you said solved the problem! thank you for your fast awnser!